# Where can I download IGARSS 2012 data fusion contest data?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

I khow that IGARSS 2012 [data fusion contest](http://www.grss-ieee.org/community/technical-committees/data-fusion/data-fusion-contest/) contained worldview/quickbird images of San Francisco. Does anyone know if that data is available for free and where can I download it?

Comment: The web site that you cited says `Data can be requested by registering for the Contest on the IEEE GRSS DASE bsite: http://dase.ticinumaerospace.com/. Participants must read and accept the Contest Terms and Conditions.`

Comment: @G5W I thought that such data are available online after the contests

Comment: If you are on LinkedIn,  you could join the  [IADF TC Discussion group](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/3678437/profile) and ask there.